# pdfsandwich - how to not change page colour

Tags: ocr

I am using pdfsandwich but it changes the colour of the pages from colour to black and white.
Since I have a document with many coloured pictures how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 3):

1. Download the latest version of [pdfsandwich](http://www.tobias-elze.de/pdfsandwich/) (at the moment of writing: 0.1.3).
2. Use option `-rgb` to preserve color:

   ```
   pdfsandwich -rgb file.pdf
   ```